# Loading multiple vector drawables from resources in recyclerview effectively

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have around 200 vector drawables in res and i'd like to show the preview of each in a recyclerview. Since I'm loading locally, is there any way to load the images effectively without jamming the UI?
I tried Glide but it's for rasters only as far as I know.

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(R.drawable.resource_id)
    .into(imageView);
```

AsynclayoutInflater is good for performance or are there any other ways?

Comment: add all resource into a list like ArrayList<Int> drawableList = new ArrayList() and pass this into recyclerView and show in on Bind with postion

Comment: @Amitpandey thats not the problem for me, I just wanted to know if there is any way to load all the images effectively without any lag? like asynchronously?

Comment: imageView.setResouce(R.drawable.any)

Comment: @Amitpandey that causes performance issue. there are a lot of images.

Comment: When we got a large amount of data in recylerView we use paggnation like first add 10 or 20 images and when its scrol down its load next 10 or 20 i used its with api if you want to try with local